# ¿Cómo cambiar el item inicial de un FragmentPagerAdapter en Android?

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

Tengo un ArrayList<> en el cual contengo 3 Fragment pero por defecto este inicia en en Item 0, yo quiero iniciar en el Item uno y que este me permita deslizarme tanto para izquierda como para la derecha.

¿Alguien sabe si puedo hacer esta personalizacion?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estás asociando a un **ViewPager** esa clase de tipo FragmentPagerAdapter.
Como puedes ver en la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide#kotlins), moverte a un item concreto de tu ViewPager es muy fácil:

```
yourViewPager.currentItem = 1
```

Donde 1 es el **índice** que representa la vista que quieres mostrar.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Estoy utilizando como adaptador el:
     FragmentPagerAdapter.

En este paso como parametro en su constructor un: 
     List lista;

Yo quiero saber si al asignar como Iten inicial el valor (1) este me permitiria deslizar tanto para la izquierda como para la derecha, es algo que hace Instagrame con su Home, Camera y Messages, Bueno algo asi reuqiero yo.

Que funcionaria?